# Why all values are the same in nested dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I'm trying to generate a nested dictionary but when for loops finish all the values are the same in every key.

```
def frequency(df, headers, numerical, target):
di = {}
if len(numerical) == 0:
    print("No NM")
else:
    for i in numerical:
        if i in headers:
            headers.remove(i)

    for i in range(len(headers)):
        attdic = {}
        valdic = {}
        aux_list = df[headers[i]].to_list()
        aux_list = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(aux_list))
        tar_list = df[target].to_list()
        tar_list = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(tar_list))

        for j in range(len(aux_list)):
            print(aux_list[j])

            for k in range(len(tar_list)):
                temp_df = df.loc[(df[headers[i]] == aux_list[j]) & (df[target] == tar_list[k])]
                tempvar = len(temp_df.index) + 1  

                valdic[tar_list[k]] = tempvar
                attdic[aux_list[j]] = valdic
                di[headers[i]] = attdic
```

Output:

```
{'Outlook': {'overcast': {'No': 2, 'Yes': 5}, 'rainy': {'No': 2, 'Yes': 5}, 'sunny': {'No': 2, 'Yes': 5}}, 'Windy': {False: {'No': 3, 'Yes': 5}, True: {'No': 3, 'Yes': 5}}}
```

Expected output:

```
{'Outlook': {'overcast': {'No': 3, 'Yes': 3}, 'rainy': {'No': 3, 'Yes': 4}, 'sunny': {'No': 2, 'Yes': 5}}, 'Windy': {False: {'No': 4, 'Yes': 6}, True: {'No': 3, 'Yes': 5}}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that you create one `valdic` for each `i`, but you should have created one for each `(i,j)`, so you can move it inside the loop for `j`, and maybe it works

```py
def frequency(df, headers, numerical, target):
di = {}
if len(numerical) == 0:
    print("No NM")
else:
    for i in numerical:
        if i in headers:
            headers.remove(i)

    for i in range(len(headers)):
        attdic = {}
        aux_list = df[headers[i]].to_list()
        aux_list = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(aux_list))
        tar_list = df[target].to_list()
        tar_list = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(tar_list))

        for j in range(len(aux_list)):
            valdic = {} # create a new valdic for each j
            print(aux_list[j])

            for k in range(len(tar_list)):
                temp_df = df.loc[(df[headers[i]] == aux_list[j]) & (df[target] == tar_list[k])]
                tempvar = len(temp_df.index) + 1  

                valdic[tar_list[k]] = tempvar
            attdic[aux_list[j]] = valdic
        di[headers[i]] = attdic
```